# Cassandra: disable CRUD with no partition key (or otherwise intercept it CQL for inspection)?

Tags: cassandra

While I suppose I could fork Cassandra and modify it to taste, is there an easier way to intercept CQL and reject it?

The whys and wherefores are too long to go into, but for several reasons I would like to enforce certain requirements on CQL run starting with performance.

To get started with a simple example, what'd be the easiest way to:

- reject CQL with 'allow filtering'
- reject CQL-SELECT without a where clause

The key point is enforcement ... in or near the server and not rely on programmers to exclude these cases.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra doesn't have such built-in capability right now. There is a movement in corresponding direction in [the DSE 6.8 where guardrails exist](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__guardrailsYaml), but it's not an open source.

But you can at least monitor queries via [audit functionality of Cassandra 4.0](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiIqeHD9_3oAhUhPn0KHQIKAhsQFjAAegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcassandra.apache.org%2Fblog%2F2018%2F10%2F29%2Faudit_logging_cassandra.html&usg=AOvVaw0tyQRNqizgKgnF_sYFavJu) (not released yet), or via E[ricsson's ecaudit plugin for 2.2/3.0/3.11](https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit).